# Problems combing fetch and res

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, fetch

I am currently trying to add 10 different values in my database through a forloop and then respond with "res 200". However it seems like res 200 runs before the loop have even started and I keep getting error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when moving it arround.

My code:

````
app.post("/api/v1/getWeatherData",async(req,res)=>{
  let sources = await db.query("SELECT * FROM weather where element = 'mean(air_temperature P1D)' LIMIT 10;")
  console.log(sources.rows)
  try{
    let count = 1
    sources.rows.map(async(source)=>{
      sleep(5000)
      fetch(`https://frost.met.no/observations/v0.jsonld?sources=${source.source_id}&referencetime=${(source.valid_from).split("T")[0]}%2F2022-02-20&elements=mean(air_temperature%20P1D)&fields=value%2C%20referenceTime`, {
              method: "get",
              body: JSON.stringify(),
              headers: {
                Authorization:
                  "MYSECRET",
              },
            })
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then(async tempData => {
                /* tempData.data.map(async (currentWeatherData)=>{
                  await db.query("INSERT INTO weather_data(weather_id,element,time,value) values ($1,'mean(air_temperature P1D)',$2,$3);",[input.rows[0].weather_id,currentWeatherData.referenceTime.split("T")[0],parseInt(currentWeatherData.observations[0].value)])
                }) */
                console.log("completed"); 
                count+=1
                console.log("happend")
    
        })
    })
if (count >=10){
    console.log(count)
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        value: "Oppdatert",
      },
    });
  }
  }
  catch(err){console.log(err)}
})```
````

Comment: correct, as you are not waiting for any of the fetch to complete - I can't see how `if (count >= 10)` could ever be true though, since that is executed before ANY of the `fetch` could even start

Comment: why are you using `.map` if you aren't returning anything in the map or using the returned array? what does `sleep(5000)` even do? why are you using `async` callback for .map, if you never `await`? mixing `async`/`await` with `.then` usually means you're doing it wrong

Comment: sure, you think, but what is the function `sleep` and how does it do that?

Comment: function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

Comment: yep, so, it won't help, since you don't wait for that promise to resolve anyway - you'd need to `await sleep(5000)` - but, the way you've written your code, all requests will wait 5 seconds, and then all requests would be made at the same time, since there's no delay between iterations in `.map`

Comment: can you explain why `if (count >=10){` ... do you only want to make exactly 10 requests? So if there's 9 rows, no response at all, and if there's 11, you only make 10? or do you make them all?

Comment: Oh wow, I misunderstood the concept I suppose. I must do some more research on how fetch and await really works I suppose as I clearly have missed something

Comment: II changed that to === 10 instead so when count is 10 then it returns res 200

Comment: `async`/`await` (and `promises` in general I guess) is often misunderstood as being some sort of magic to make asynchronous code synchronous ... you need to realise that's not the case, while async/await just allows you to write synchronous looking code, an `async function` is, by its very definition, asynchronous

Comment: `changed that to === 10` yeah, so that doesn't answer the question I asked ... if there are only 9 rows, what should happen, if there are more than 10 rows, what should happen

Comment: If that is the case than res 500 would be approriate

Comment: so, if there isn't exactly 10 rows, you want to respond with a 500?

Comment: Correct, the limit 10 is not a permanent thing. In the future I will remove the limit 10 and instead make a check that returns 200 when I have gotten all the values from loop through a if sentence that checks length vs count for example

Comment: so if there's more than 10, you just want to do the first 10 for now (without an error)

Comment: My plan, for now, was to get 10 destinations from the database, then fetch some values for these 10 destinations, and then apply them into the database again. I don't know how it can be more than 10 in this scenario since I have "Limit 10". In the future, I will replace the if sentence with the length of the array instead. But for now I found it appropriate to only work with 10 values.

Comment: fair enough, just wanted clarity

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the `fetch()` operations to be done before your counter will be valid.  The simplest way to do that is to sequence them by using `await` like this:

```
app.post("/api/v1/getWeatherData", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let sources = await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM weather where element = 'mean(air_temperature P1D)' LIMIT 10;")
        let count = 1;
        for (let source of sources.rows) {
            await sleep(5000);
            let res = await fetch(
                `https://frost.met.no/observations/v0.jsonld?sources=${source.source_id}&referencetime=${(source.valid_from).split("T")[0]}%2F2022-02-20&elements=mean(air_temperature%20P1D)&fields=value%2C%20referenceTime`, {
                    method: "get",
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "MYSECRET",
                    },
                });
            let tempData = await res.json();
            /* tempData.data.map(async (currentWeatherData)=>{
              await db.query("INSERT INTO weather_data(weather_id,element,time,value) values ($1,'mean(air_temperature P1D)',$2,$3);",[input.rows[0].weather_id,currentWeatherData.referenceTime.split("T")[0],parseInt(currentWeatherData.observations[0].value)])
            }) */
            console.log("completed");
            count += 1
            console.log("happend")

        }
        if (count >= 10) {
            console.log(count)
            res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
                data: {
                    value: "Oppdatert",
                },
            });
        }
    } catch (err) { 
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

**Summary of Changes:**

1. Add `await` to `fetch()` and to `res.json()`
2. Move try/catch up to catch all errors, including on the `await db.query()`
3. Remove the `body` argument from the `fetch()` call as no body should be sent with the GET request.
4. Add `res.sendStatus(500)` to the catch handler so a response of some kind is always sent.  You can obviously change that to whatever response is appropriate when there's an error, but you must send some response.
5. Add `await` in front of `sleep(5000)` since it wasn't actually doing anything without that.  Note, this means it will take 50 seconds (5 * 10) to send a response back to the client.

**Note:**

In the case where count is not >= 10, you probably need an `else` statement and send some sort of response there because all paths through this code must send some sort of http response.  I'm not sure what you're trying to test for there.

---

If you want to and can run all the requests in parallel, you could also do that by accumulating the promises and using `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done like this:

```
app.post("/api/v1/getWeatherData", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let sources = await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM weather where element = 'mean(air_temperature P1D)' LIMIT 10;")
        let count = 1;
        await Promise.all(sources.rows.map(async source => {
            let res = await fetch(
                `https://frost.met.no/observations/v0.jsonld?sources=${source.source_id}&referencetime=${(source.valid_from).split("T")[0]}%2F2022-02-20&elements=mean(air_temperature%20P1D)&fields=value%2C%20referenceTime`, {
                    method: "get",
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "MYSECRET",
                    },
                });
            let tempData = await res.json();
            /* tempData.data.map(async (currentWeatherData)=>{
              await db.query("INSERT INTO weather_data(weather_id,element,time,value) values ($1,'mean(air_temperature P1D)',$2,$3);",[input.rows[0].weather_id,currentWeatherData.referenceTime.split("T")[0],parseInt(currentWeatherData.observations[0].value)])
            }) */
            console.log("completed");
            count += 1
            console.log("happend")
        }));
        if (count >= 10) {
            console.log(count)
            res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
                data: {
                    value: "Oppdatert",
                },
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: by the way, the `sleep(5000)` was important (read OPs comments) to avoid "too many requests" - so the parallel requests code should not be an option :p

Comment: @Bravo - OK, I put `await sleep(5000)` back into the first implementation and added a comment about  the parallel option.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked wonders, now what is the best way sleep(5000) between each fetch in the loop as the answer I found on google clearly didn't have a impact?

Comment: @OleDybedokken - I put `await sleep(5000)` back into the first code block in my answer.  If you really want to pause 5 seconds between requests and `sleep()` is what you showed in your comment (returns a promise that resolves on a timer), then that should work.  But, this will make the whole thing take 5000 * 10 = 50 seconds before it finishes and sends an http response.